# What is actually happening in memory in Fortran common blocks?

Tags: memory, fortran, fortran-common-block

I'm coming into Fortran with a heavy C background.  It's all pretty straightforward, except the actual mechanisms of how common blocks work baffles me, and I can't find any place that describes them in detail.

Let's say I have the following common block:

```
COMMON/MYBLOCK/ A,B,C
```

As I understand this, this will set aside a chunk of memory that contains three...things, that aren't really associated with the names in the block, and in fact if If have this next code later in my source:

```
SUBROUTINE MYSUB(...)
...
COMMON/MYBLOCK/ X,Y,Z
...
END
```

Then now X is associated with whatever used to be in A, and the same Y to B and Z to C.

So this means `COMMON/MYBLOCK/` is...an array of void pointers when it's declared?  There's no type associated with any of these pointers, so...memory is allocated when a value is assigned?  What happens if I say `A='A'` in my main thread, but then in `MYSUB` I say `A=3.141592`?  If I have a subroutine that I want to return a value into `A` by reference (because it's part of an external library), can I just say `CALL MYSUB2(A)` and count on the compiler to sort it out?  Or do I need to call `MYSUB2` on a local variable first, then assign that to `A`?

It's weird, Fortran is such a strongly typed language everywhere else, but common blocks are just like "do whatever you want, man, we don't do types here"...

Comment: Why do you want to use common? They shouldn't have been used in new code for 3 decades. Use modules if you really must have global state and forget you ever saw common - you will sleep better for it. Or are you looking at old code?

Comment: You mean there are C programmers out there who work on FORTRAN for anything but legacy 30-year-old code?  In all seriousness, I have old legacy code with `COMMON` all over the place, and I'm trying to understand what it's doing under the hood.

Comment: Get a copy of the working draft of the Fortran 2018 standard (search for N2146.pdf).  Read section 8.10 on storage association.  If you have old code that contains a lot of `COMMON` blocks, then it likely uses `EQUIVALENCE` statements.   In any event, Section 8.10.2.1 starts with _The COMMON statement specifies blocks of physical storage, called common blocks, that can be accessed by any of the scoping units in a program. Thus, the COMMON statement provides a global data facility based on storage association (19.5.3)._

Comment: If I'm following what's happening, I think all the `COMMON` blocks in the code I'm looking at are being used to store either `REAL`s or arrays containing `REAL`s so implicit typing is enough?  Searching the .f file doesn't yield any `EQUIVALENCE` statements. EDIT: Never mind, there are some `I<VAR>`s in there too, so ints and reals both.  Still, all implicitly typed

Comment: Implicit typing is evil as it can lead to errors.  You can think of a `COMMON` block as a global static struct in C where the names of the components are determined from the `COMMON block statement and its position in the `COMMON` block.

Comment: @evets Yeah, and I swear EVERY SINGLE EXAMPLE I tried to look up to understand `COMMON` blocks used it, like implicit typing is just some standard Fortran good-coding practice instead of (I hope) some horrid deprecated wart on the Fortran standard that's only maintained for backwards compatibility.

Comment: That is just because modern codes with good practice do not use common blocks. So those that do remain... They are usually ancient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not confuse what the standard language allows you and what you can get away with in existing compilers and what people use in various legacy codes.

Common blocks are a place for **static storage** that can be **accessed  from various compilation units**. The variables stored there are accessed using the common block name and the position (offset) of the variable inside the common block.

Whether the common blocks end up in the .data segment .bss segment is an implementation detail for a particular platform. But in practice on the platforms common today, the common blocks will appear in one of those.

It is not here for type punning. One may not reference the same memory location as different types. It shall be always accessed as a single type. You can get away using the same memory location as different types only if you separate the usage. You cannot write a real and read an integer.

**The variables stored in common blocks certainly DO have a type. The type may be declared explicitly or determined using the implicit typing rules.**

```
 IMPLICIT NONE
 
 COMMON /BLOCK1/ A, B, C
 
 END
```

will give you

```
> gfortran common.f90 
common.f90:3:18:

  COMMON /BLOCK1/ A, B, C
                  1
Error: Symbol ‘a’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
common.f90:3:21:

  COMMON /BLOCK1/ A, B, C
                     1
Error: Symbol ‘b’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
common.f90:3:24:

  COMMON /BLOCK1/ A, B, C
                        1
Error: Symbol ‘c’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

and you will have to declare the type of the variables explicitly.

Without seeing anything more from your code we have to conclude that your variables are of type `real` by the implicit typing rules, unless an explicit `IMPLICIT` statement imposes different implicit typing rules.

Comment: This didn't really answer my question, but Googling around tells me that `IMPLICIT NONE` basically tells Fortran to not default everything with no explicit type to `REAL` or `INT` depending on the name?  So what really happens in my code above is `A`,`B`, and `C` get instantiated as `REAL`s without an `IMPLICIT NONE` directive?

Comment: No.  Without `IMPLICIT NONE`, implicit typing rules kick.  `A`, `B`, and `C` are then default real kind variables.  On common hardware of today, each likely occupies 4 storage units.

Comment: I have added a brief explanation of what a common block actually is but it seemed from your question that you knew that and you were only wondering why those variables :do not have any type:,

Comment: The edit you made at the end helps, because the bolded part assumes a bit too much knowledge on whether I'm aware `IMPLICIT` exists or the mechanisms of how it works.  Every example that's been put in front of me (including the code I'm working on) was using implicit typing without calling it out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Things can be more complicated...
The first occurrence of the named block will define the total size of memory allocated to the named block, but when referenced one can change the names of the variables, their order and their type. The subroutine will access the memory and assign the corresponding values to the variables. This is prone to error, but was used in older codes to optimize (minimize) the use of memory.

```
COMMON /BLOCK1/ A(3)
```

is equivalent to

```
COMMON /BLOCK1/ A, B, C
```

or

```
COMMON /BLOCK1/ X, Y, Z
```

and the compiler may also accept

```
COMMON /BLOCK1/ A, B, I1, I2
```

where implicit real and integer types are used.

Additional confusion can occur when the named block is referenced more than once in the same subroutine, but this is simply a continuation of the list of variables. See [Intel's Fortran compiler guide reference](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/fortran-compiler/developer-guide-reference/2023-1/common.html#GUID-C3848B56-3548-4B88-83D5-00472567E0E3).